# Using "and that "

Tags: conjunctions

While I was searching for the meaning of the word "*libertarianism*" below

> The adherents of libertarianism believe that private morality is not the state's affair **and that** therefore activities such as drug use and prostitution, which arguably harm no one but the participants, should not be illegal.

Why is "and that" used instead of just "and" ?

Comment: It helps with the parsing.

Comment: Some people like to use "that" when it is clearly understood, therefore unnecessary. "The adherents of libertarianism believe *that* private morality... and *that* therefore..." I believe, however, the second *that* is more 'necessary' to understanding the statement than the first. People have choices when writing. There are some hard and fast rules, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

One answer here is that stylistically, parallel structure helps.  One approach which maintains parallel structure is to get of *both* thats, which is to say

> The adherents of libertarianism believe private morality is not the state's affair and therefore activities...

Each "that" plays the same role of demarcating "these are the things that adherents of Libertarianism believe".